# Why session behave differently?

Tags: php, session

I am using three PHP files

**Create.php**

```
session_name('testing') ;
session_start() ;

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    header('Location: get.php') ;
    die() ;
}
session_regenerate_id() ;
$_SESSION['id'] = '35' ;   
$_SESSION['name'] = 'gaurav' ;

session_write_close() ;
```

**Get.php**

```
session_name('testing') ; 

session_start() ;
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    header('Location: create.php') ;
    die() ;
}
echo $_SESSION['id']," = ",$_SESSION['name'] ;

?>
<form action="close.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Log out"></input> 
</form>
```

**close.php**

```
session_name('testing') ; 
session_start() ;  
session_destroy() ;
```

When I process the `create->get->close` is correct because I  destroy session in close so their will no session available but after close I go on  create.php which redirect to me in get.php mean there is session variable set.
but when I go on close.php to get.php which  redirects to create.php which is right behavior but I don't understand that close->create a redirect to me get.php .

The second question is that when I create.php make two session files in a tmp folder every time one file will be blank but second have all values.

Comment: There seem to be at least 3 separate questions here...can you refactor this as 1 question?

Comment: try doing a var_dump($_SESSION) on line 3 of Create.php to see why it's falling into the redirect if

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob  they are occurring with same script

Comment: @Michael after close to create than is show session array  with value

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be due to the use of 
`session_regenerate_id() ;`

*session_regenerate_id() will replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the current session information.* 
This is taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php 
I think that since you're not deleting the old session, you're ending up with two sessions, and only destroying one. This is just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks , but that's why i assure that  the name should be same . if not than session_start() new session, destroy fucntion destroy new not old one